# 960 Grid System is actually 1180 wide. How to fix it?

Tags: drupal, 960.gs

I am using 960gs and seems it is ok so far. I am using it with Drupal Omega Theme but this is a minor detail. I chose a normal layout not fluid.

ISSUE:
**I have a problem because my actual width is 1180 instead 960**. Can someone tell me why.

I notice each (pink) column of the grid measures 80px instead 60px on 12 columns layout (normal).

If I switch to 16 columns it has 55px instead 40px. Weird!

I tried on different Drupal installs with different content but found no clue. Thanks

[image: My 960 grid system in Drupa Omega Theme]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drupal's Omega Theme is a responsive layout, meaning it actually has a narrower and a wider version of the 960 Grid. You can see this when you resize your browser to a smaller width.

The different Grid sizes can be disabled in the Omega Theme settings. In Drupal 7, go to Appearance -> Settings -> Your Theme name.You can then:

- disable the responsive Layout completely (remove the checkmark in front of "Enable the responsive grid" on the top of the settings page, forcing only 960 or whatever layout you select as Primary Layout)

or

- disable the narrow and wide variations of the layout further down the page. (Checkbox in front of "Use this layout with the responsive grid")

Comment: Actually I deactivate the wide variations. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably loading other CSS file / rules that are overriding the default 960 width. Have you checked that?

Comment: yes there is no such rule. I notice my columns are 80 pixels wide instead 60. wtf?

Answer (score 0):

Padding and margin of columns is not calculated in width, so you have to factor that in!

ie:

```
div
{
   width:100px;
   margin:10px;
   padding:10px;
}
```

will have a total of 140px width. Added to that is also any border it may have!

Comment: I was talking about the pink columns. They are supposed to have no margin/padding/border, they're just images. If you check in my attachement pic (in full view) you can measure by yourself. I simply can't figure out.